# Delete having a certain sum

Tags: sql

I need a query where I need to delete several lines from a table if the sum of hours is 120 for a certain employee

My original query is

```
delete from [CompanyB$Employee Hours]
where [Employee ID] = 'A2054'
  and sum(Hours) = '120'
```

Help!

Thanks,

When I use the query below,it shows 0 rows affected

The Employee Hour table contains records like the ones below

Sequence|Employee|ID Hours
1|1024|2.50
2|1024|-2.50
3|1024|4.0
4|1024|1.0
5|1024|-2.0

Total Sum of Hours = 3

Similarly,I want to delete record of a certain employee if the sum of hours = x

I tried the solution and resulted with empty results
Query is being tried in Sql server 2008

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, your question is tagged MySQL, but it uses square braces which would cause a syntax error in that database.  Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: On the other hand, which dbms allows `'120'` as a numeric literal?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
DELETE t
FROM [CompanyB$Employee Hours] t
INNER JOIN (select s.[Employee ID],sum(s.hours) as sumHours
            FROM [CompanyB$Employee Hours] s 
            GROUP BY s.[Employee ID]) tt
 ON(t.[Employee ID] = tt.[Employee ID] and sumHours = 120)
```

This will delete each employee that has total of 120 hours.

You can add a where clause to filter specific uses.

Comment: It's a bit unclear which dbms OP uses. But if this works with both MySQL and SQL Server, OP will probably be pleased.

Comment: Sry, I'm not following, change the 120 to whatever the sum you want, it should work perfectly @Sequel3